# Is this a correct usage of “gravitas”?

Tags: connotation

The word *gravitas* is usually used in reference to a human quality. Can it also be used correctly in the following example?

> The use of the time-worn stones for the steps gives an instant air of gravitas to the design. (landscape architecture reference)

Comment: Yes, it can be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are anthropomorphizing the stones, then sure, "gravitas," a word originating in the Ancient Roman [virtues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtus_(virtue)) makes perfect sense in this context.  The steps "give an ... air of gravitas," because that is the emotion they inspire in the viewer.  This is an anthropomorphization because the stones don't actually "give" anything.

Architecture is an art that gives human meaning to inorganic slabs of rock on the grandest of scales.  The metaphoric use of human attributes to describe it is not only appropriate but will breathe life into your prose.